# What's the deal with this question's stats?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

[My pre-schooler is out of control, and I feel like my parents are undermining my relationship and authority with her](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/my-pre-schooler-is-out-of-control-and-i-feel-like-my-parents-are-undermining-my)

This question has been viewed 10k times and has been asked only 2 days ago. What is the source of its popularity?

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that I see having happened with the question.

The first, and probably the biggest factor, is that it made the Stack Exchange "Hot Network Questions" list.  This gives it visibility on *ever* stack exchange site, and was clearly the source of a lot of people coming over here.

The second is that it was Tweeted by Stack Exchange on the Parenting.se feed.  This isn't likely to have as much impact, since there are only 61 followers (I'm one, but I'm rarely on twitter, and didn't see it).

Between the two of these, though, we've clearly gotten a lot of new visits.  Many of them seem to be new to the SE network, so perhaps there are other factors at play, as well.

Either way, clearly getting a question listed as a "Hot Network Question" is a good thing :)

Comment: So what do we have to do to a question to push it into the "hot network questions" list?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I'm not sure if this is current, but [here is what I found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/166646).

Comment: Update: as [was pointed out in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13251200#13251200), the correct formula appears to be [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343).